# How to use list comprehension as a condition in a list comprehension?

Tags: string, list, haskell, list-comprehension

I want to get only the capital letters from a string, and had the idea to see if each letter in the string is contained in a list of all capital letters:

```
capsOnly = [ x| x<- string, (x elem ['A'..'Z'])]
```

the problem is that apparently Haskell does not recognize that the part behind the comma is supposed to be a condition for x, and gives me this:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `(a0 -> t0 a0 -> Bool)
                                -> [Char] -> Bool'
              with actual type `Char'
* The function `x' is applied to two arguments,
  but its type `Char' has none
  In the expression: (x elem ['A' .. 'Z'])
  In a stmt of a list comprehension: (x elem ['A' .. 'Z'])
```

So how do I define what is the Argument and what is the List where x comes from?
Or is that not possible?

I know that you can also do it like:

```
onlyCaps = [ x| x<- string, x < 'a']
```

but I really want to know if my first approach is possible, and how to write it if it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is **not with the list comprehension** itself. The problem is that `x elem ['A'..'Z']` does not make much sense.

**[`elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) is a function** that takes as input an element and a list and checks if the element belongs to the list.

So you should write it like:

```
capsOnly = [ x | x <- string, elem x ['A'..'Z']]
```

Or alternatively use backtics (to use *infix* notation):

```
capsOnly = [ x | x <- string, x `elem` ['A'..'Z']]
```

This however is *not* very efficient: it requires *O(n)* to check membership. Since we check a range, it is more efficient to do bound checks, like:

```
capsOnly = [ x | x <- string, x >= 'A', x <= 'Z']
```

This requires two comparisons that run in *O(1)* making it faster.

What we do here is filtering. Usually it is better (more descriptive and declarative) to use [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) for this with [`isAsciiUpper :: Char -> Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isAsciiUpper) as predicate:

```
import Data.Char(isAsciiUpper)

capsOnly = filter isAsciiUpper string
```

Comment: Or `[ x | x <- string, x \`elem\` ['A'..'Z']]` (probably what the OP was trying to write in the first place)

Comment: @jwodder: I was thinking exactly the same :)

Comment: Are we sure that GHC wouldn't optimize `elem x ['A'..'Z']` to `x >= 'A', x <= 'Z'`..?

Comment: Well for floating points that law does not hold. For instance `elem 0.5 [0..9]` is `False` whereas `0.5 >= 0 && 0.5 <= 9` holds. Furthermore some benchmarks suggest it does not.

Comment: @Redu you can check by ddump-simpl both versions and comparing them

Comment: @jwodder yeah, the whole thing was just forgetting that elem isnt infix by default.